# Decode and Parse JSON to Lua

Tags: json, parsing, lua

I have following JSON data I would like to decode to Lua to access each the publish_topic and sample_rate value.

```
{"00-06-77-2f-37-94":{"publish_topic":"/stations/test","sample_rate":5000}}
```

If I understand correctly the Lua table will look like this:

```
{00-06-77-2f-37-94 = "publish_topic":"/stations/test","sample_rate":5000}
```

Next I would go through the table to save each value into a local variable.

However, if I try printing out the values of the table (using following code), I get 'nil' as return. Is the code for reading table values wrong?
Does the table have two values or is it just the one: ["publish_topic":"/stations/test","sample_rate":5000] ?

```
lua_value = JSON:decode(data)
  
  for _,d in pairs(lua_value) do
    print(lua_value[d])
  end

local topic = lua_value[0]
local timer = lua_value[1]

end
```

Edit: I am using following JSON library for Lua: http://regex.info/blog/lua/json

Edit2: *@Piglet*: I implemented your script and modified it by adding a table (conversionTable) in which both elements "publish_topic":"/stations/test" and "sample_rate:5000" would be respectively saved in the variables pubtop and rate. When I however print each of both variables, nil ist returned in both cases.
How can I extract the information out of this table to save in variables?

Ultimately I actually only would like to save the values "/stations/test" and "5000" into these variables. Would I need to parse each of the elements above to get these or is there another way?

```
local pubtop
local rate
local function printTable(t)
  local conversionTable = {}
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if type(v) == "table" then
      conversionTable [k] = string.format("%q: {", k)
      printTable(v)
      print("}")
    else
      print(string.format("%q:", k) .. v .. ",")
    end
  end

  pubtop = conversionTable[0]
  rate = conversionTable[1]
  
end

local lua_value
local function handleOnReceive(topic, data, _, _)
  print("handleOnReceive: topic '" .. topic .. "' message '" .. data .. "'")
  -- This sample publishes the received messages to test/topic2
  print(data)
  lua_value = JSON:decode(data)

  printTable(lua_value)

  print(pubtop)
  print(rate)
end
client:register('OnReceive', handleOnReceive)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which json library you're using so I can't tell you wether JSON:decode(data) is the correct way.

Assuming lua_value would like like so:

```
local lua_value = {
  ["00-06-77-2f-37-94"] = {
    publish_topic = "/stations/test",
    sample_rate = 5000
  }
}
```

Then your loop

```
for _,d in pairs(lua_value) do
    print(lua_value[d])
  end
```

will indeed print `nil`.

`lua_value` has a single element at key `"00-06-77-2f-37-94"` which is a table.

Each loop iteration will give you a key value pair. So `d` is actually the value and hence the inner table of `lua_value`

So you're actually doing this:

```
local innerTable = lua_value["00-06-77-2f-37-94"]
print(lua_value[innerTable])
```

Of course `lua_value[innerTable]` is `nil`.

### Edit:

Try something like

```
function printTable(t)
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if type(v) == "table" then
      print(string.format("%q: {", k))
      printTable(v)
      print("}")
    else
      print(string.format("%q:", k) .. v .. ",")
    end
  end
end

printTable(lua_value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated the question with the library I use. What would an appropriate loop be for me to access publish_topic and sample_rate?

Comment: Thanks, please see Edit2

Comment: @WhatIsProtocoll please aska new question instead of extending your question to solve further problems. we do not discuss problems by adding stuff to questions and answers back and forth. that creates a mess.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know. Link to new question is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66195713/15044065